# I cant remove this odd outline from my button in wordpress(new to css)

Tags: css, wordpress, button

Hello so I am making a site: https://outlandbot.xyz and there is a button that says **INVITE NOW**, the problem is that I don't like that white border around the button. I tried everything in CSS and I don't have an FTP client, only the additional CSS tab in WordPress.

My code:

```
wp-block-button:focus {
padding: 0;
border: none;
background: none;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that when I go online I try to find my button class and put in the code, wordpress just does not word with me. I tried button css and it still does not work.

Comment: Here is my code that I put in:

wp-block-button:focus {
 padding: 0;
border: none;
background: none;
}

Comment: The white outline you see there is not a border or an outline, it's a pseudo-element Within that `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [pseudo element :before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) attached to your button in your styles:

```
.button:before, 
.wp-block-button__link:before, 
.wp-block-file__button:before, 
.a8c-posts-list__view-all:before {
    border: 2px solid;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    height: calc(100% - 6px);
    width: calc(100% - 6px);
}
```

Just get rid of those. Or overwrite your button:

```
.wp-block-button__link:before {
    content: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!